# Loop construct logic in OCA sample quiz

Tags: java, for-loop

This was a question on my sample OCA Java quiz.  The book says I answered incorrectly.  I walked through the logic again, and even ran it through netbeans ide to make sure.  The output was in fact my original answer, not the answer the book says is correct.  I am confused, can someone please verify!

Question:

```
import static java.lang.System.*;
class _ {
   static public void main (String [] __A_V_) {
   String $ = "";

   for (int x=0; ++x < __A_V_.length; )
       $ += __A_V_[x];

   out.println($);
   }
}
```

And the command line: `Java _ - A .`

What is the result:

(A) -A

(B) A.

(C) -A.

(D) _A.

(E) _-A.

(F) Compilation fails

(G) An exeception is thrown at runtime

I followed the logic and originally came to the answer of (c).

The book says (b) is correct.  Here is the book's explanation: "This question is using valid (but inappropriate and weird) identifiers, static imports, main(), and pre-incrementing logic.

I checked with the IDE and it verified I was correct with the answer of (c).

Is the book incorrect or am I missing something?

Comment: I have to ask, what's with the variable and class names?

Comment: @DrewKennedy it's a test prep question so they're just testing your knowledge of legal identifiers.

Comment: Ahh, seeing that in your question now. I looked at the code and immediately my brain started leaking through my ears and didn't read the rest lol.

Comment: So when I run the project, and use ` args = new String[] { "java", "_", "-", "A" };` to populate the array, I get answer E, which is what I was expecting. Also, unless `$` was declared somewhere, the code wouldn't compile.

Comment: "Java" isn't a command line argument, it's a command-line command. The "_","-","A","." after the java command are the elements of the args array.  But, if "java" were the first (index 0) of the args array, I would also get the answer of E just like you.

Comment: Also, you are correct about the declaration of variable $.  I omitted that line of code accidentally.  Sorry, I'll fix that.

Comment: Then the answer is C. The pre-increment will skip the first element and concatenate the rest.

Comment: That's what I originally answered, but according to the book I am incorrect.  Thank you for verifying that!!

Answer (score 0):

OK sorry for the post, it finally clicked!  "java _" is the command line command telling the JVM to execute class _.

I was thinking the underscore was the first element (index 0) of the args array.

But, it's the classname to which the java command is executing.

Which means, at run time, the args args array at index 0 is -, index 1 is A, index 2 is .